# Handlebars has no method 'html'

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

If I console.log($('#result-template').html()), I get:

```
{{#each this}}
<tr>
    <td>{{MfgName}}</td>
    <td><button type="submit" name="MfgID" value="{{MfgID}}">Select</button></td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

But when I do:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile('#result-template').html();
```

I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (context, options) { } has no
>   method 'html'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean:

`var template = Handlebars.compile($('#result-template').html());`

Comment: Ahhh, this could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks Paul!  I think that's it!  On to the next syntax error!

Answer (score 1):

`Handlebars.compile` returns a `function` representing the template, not a jQuery object. There is no HTML until the template function is called.